# Car collision buggy on all sides of car

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have created a JavaScript game where my vehicle moves around on the map and now need to build in collision logic. To date, I have tried to predict collisions ahead of the car by checking to see what tileset it corresponds to. The code for this can be seen below.

```
Game.update = function () {
  const x = this.car.x;
  const y = this.car.y;

  if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = -1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT)) {
    Car.moveAngle = 1
    this._rotate(Car.moveAngle)
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.UP)) {
    Car.frontCollision = !isCarInFrontCollision(x, y)
    Car.rearCollision = !isCarInRearCollision(x, y)
    if (!Car.frontCollision || Car.rearCollision) {
      Car.speed = 2
      this.car.move();
    }
  }
  else if (Keyboard.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN)) {
    Car.frontCollision = !isCarInFrontCollision(x, y)
    Car.rearCollision = !isCarInRearCollision(x, y)
    if (!Car.rearCollision || Car.frontCollision) {
      Car.speed = -2
      this.car.move();
    }
  }
  else {
    decelerate();
  }
  this.camera.update();
};

function isCarInRearCollision(x, y) {
  return !map.isSolidTileAtBottom(x, y)
}

function isCarInFrontCollision(x, y) {
  return !map.isSolidTileAtTop(x, y) 
}
```

This (sorta) works fine for front and and rear collisions when the car is north or south. But it still feels a bit dodgy. Secondly, I can't seem to figure out how to get collision working for the tiles on the east/west side of the map. Is there a better approach to doing this then what I am doing right now?

I have pushed the entirety of the code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/pfm9V5y1SyL3aQIo to demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident that the car will move less than a tile each frame, you could calculate the car's new coordinates first and then check if it would overlap with a solid tile. If it would overlap, then don't bother moving it (and zeroize the speed I guess).

In this way, your collision detection wouldn't need to reason about which direction the car is moving. Should simplify things.